# VBA CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteAsTableSourceFormatting") with link to Source

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I pasted a table from Excel into PowerPoint with this code:

```
pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteAsTableSourceFormatting")
```

Everything works fine. But how do I link it to the source range?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function provided by @JamieG to get a reference to the pasted shape([Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35060944/2912011)), Then you can access a range of that pasted shape by accessing the linked properties:

```
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = GetPastedShape()

'Assuming the pasted shape contains a excel spreadsheet
If shp.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
    shp.OLEFormat.Object.Workbook.Sheet(1).Range("A1")
End If
```